# Is there any reason why Selection.Paste is not working?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

The last line of the following code raises an error. If I change it to `Selection.Value = 3`, it works. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Error is "438" Object doesn't support this property or method.

```vb
Sub report()

  Worksheets(4).Select

  Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="C_100175"
   
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 9).Select

  Selection.Copy


  Worksheets(2).Select


  Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="C_100175"

   
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 72).Select

  Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: try .PasteSpecial

Comment: thanks Tomasz i tried that too but no luck there.

Comment: Please update you post with the code and description of the error that was raised

Comment: thanks  Super symmetry. Updated with error message. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: i am trying to get a bit more familiar with vba and what i want is to replicate what i would normally do with index/match or vlookup. I have two sheets with asset id numbers. I want to filter sheet one by a specific id and copy one value (ex. area sqm) and paste it to sheet two under column "area sqm" which corresponds to the same id. Any ideas?

Comment: i have tried this one too. along with .pastespecial. Error is still the same.

Comment: You are AutoFilter'ing a range Then Selecting visible cells.  That may result in a non-contiguous range selection.  Pasting into a non-contiguous range doesn't work.  If you update your question with some sample data (as text) and your expected results,  someone will suggest an alternative

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will throw such an error if there are no visible cells in the specified range.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to update the  whole column (BT/72) in your destination worksheet. If that's the case, try this **(not tested)**

```vb
Sub report()
    'Change 2 to the destination sheet name. e.g. Sheets("Sheet2")
    'Always work with either sheet names or better sheet code names
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    
    'Change "Sheet2" to the actual source sheet name
    'Alternatively, remove this variable and update the formula below
    Dim sSrcSht As String: sSrcSht = "Sheet2"
    
    With wsDest.Range("BT2:BT" & wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(OFFSET(" & sSrcSht & "!$I$1,MATCH(B2," & sSrcSht & "!B:B,0)-1,0),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

*Please make sure you remove all filters*